# Server sends email to selective domains only

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, joomla3.0

I am using Joomla Mailer to send email notifications to users and admin. The issue is the server can only send emails to gmail, outlook and yahoo(those are the only ones i tested). But it cant send to other domains like xxxx@mysite.com.

All the mails are sent to multiple recipients, some recipients have the gmail,hotmail or yahoo mail, others have custom mail eg xxxx@mysite.com or yyy@myothersite.com.

The ones using gmail,yahoo or hotmail can receive the mails, but the ones using custom mails cannot. What might be the issue.

I am sending emails using a genuine email for my site.

I have checked the server PTR records using http://www.intodns.com  and everything seems ok.

Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a SMTP server to send out the mail? Other hosts might think your headers look spammy. This article goes over setting up email to use SMTP instead of the mail() function.

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/how-to/configure-email-over-smtp

Comment: I followed the tutorial above.
Though it's behaves just the same way after following the steps above. At least now i can almost say the problem is at server level. Meanwhile let me contact the isp